# How to read multiple values in a single POST variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, http-post

I have a POST variable `'IMG'` that has multiple values like this example:

```
IMG=url.com/img1.png|url.com/img2.png|url.com/img3.png&...
```

So the three URL of the images are separated by `|` but are in a single `POST` variable.

What is the best method to properly read and handle these values?
I need to have these values as separate variables or as an array to properly handle them.

Comment: You could maybe just explode the post variable? `$newArray = explode('|', $_POST['IMG'])` ? :)

Comment: Why not pass them as an array in the first place?

Comment: If you show us how this value is generated, we may be able to give you an even better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string using `|` as the delimiter:

```
<?php
$urls = explode("|", $_POST['IMG']);

echo $urls[0]; // url.com/img1.png
echo $url[1]; // url.com/img2.png
echo $url[2]; // url.com/img3.png
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```php
$images = explode('|', $_POST['IMG']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way is to check if POST variable IMG exists first. Then explode its contents using PHP explode() function.

```
$image_urls = array(); //blank array assuming there are no image URLs
if(isset($_POST['IMG']))
{
  $image_urls = explode('|', $_POST['IMG']); 
}


//Below code will check if the array actually has image URL parts from 
//POST variable IMG
if(count($image_urls) > 0)
{
  //your code to process the images
}
```